# selenium select outlook attachment upload

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webbrowser-control, browser-automation

I want to upload attachement of a email using selenium in outlook. But when I am clicking on the attachment button, it shows the file manager window but I can't select any file using selenium.

How can I select a file?

```py
pyperclip.copy(os.path.join(self.attachment_root, random_file))
file_upload_window = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")))

file_upload_window.send_keys(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(self.attachment_dir, random_file)))
file_upload_window.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536570/uploading-a-file-attachment-to-outlook-office-365-email-using-selenium-python

Comment: it's not solving my problem, I have solved it in another way. Thanks.